# Best practice for running useEffect on Only One Dependency While Having Multiple Dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My goal is to update a state array only when a specific state (`loadingStatus`) changes. However, if I include only one `loadingStatus` as a dependency, React yells at me saying I need to include all `[loadingStatus, message, messageArray, setMessageArray]` as dependencies.

```js
const [loadingStatus, setLoadingStatus] = useState<string>("Idle");
const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");
const [messageArray, setMessageArray] = useState<string[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (loadingStatus === 'Loaded') {
    setMessageArray([...messageArray, message]);
  }
}, [loadingStatus, message, messageArray, setMessageArray]);
```

**Issue with having multiple dependencies:**
I want the `useEffect` to run only when `loadingStatus` changes to `'Loaded'`. However, since the code inside useEffect will update `messageArray`, this useEffect will be triggered again, potentially leading to infinite loop.

**Questions:**

1. How can I ensure `useEffect` runs only in response to `loadingStatus` changes while still safely accessing and updating `messageArray` based on the current `message`?
2. Are there best practices or patterns to follow when you need to react to a specific dependency change in `useEffect`, but also need to use other state variables within the effect?
3. Perhaps the way I set up this code is horrible. Could you please advise on how I can restructure this?

I'm looking for strategies to manage this scenario efficiently, ensuring the component remains responsive to `loadingStatus` changes without causing render issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's best recommended not to use `useEffect` for this scenario. `useEffect` is meant to be used as for a side effect rather than a subscription. Reference: https://react.dev/learn/removing-effect-dependencies

I think in your case it's best to move your condition to the event handler associated with `loadingStatus`

Eg.

```js
function setLoadingStatus(loadingStatusInput) {
  setLoadingStatus(loadingStatusInput)
  if (loadingStatusInput === 'Loaded') {
    setMessageArray([...messageArray, message]);
  }
}
```

However if you would like to still use `useEffect`:

If you know for a fact that you would only want to run this code on one dependency and know for a fact about what the other dependencies do, you can skip adding the dependencies to the array and suppress the warning. It should ideally not cause any dependency bugs as long as you know what you are doing.

```js
const [loadingStatus, setLoadingStatus] = useState<string>("Idle");
const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");
const [messageArray, setMessageArray] = useState<string[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (loadingStatus === 'Loaded') {
    setMessageArray([...messageArray, message]);
  }
}, [loadingStatus]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```